# Computer is unable to load a newly burned ISO

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, 32-bit, windows-installation

Every time i try to install a new Windows, I get this error:

> **Compatibility report**
>   The computer started using the Windows installation media. 
>   Remove the installation media and restart your computer
>   so that Windows starts normally. 
>   Then, insert the installation media and restart the upgrade. 
>   (Do not select <kbd>Custom (advanced)</kbd> to perform an upgrade. 
>   <kbd>Custom (advanced)</kbd> installs a new copy of Windows
>   and deletes your programs and settings.)
>   <sub>(Transcribed manually)</sub>

Image:

[image: "Compatibility report" error message]

I tried the following:

- install a three different Windows 10
- install two different Windows 7
- I tried to update the BIOS and I already done

I don't know what else to do!

Answer (score 1):

After communicating with the original poster, Mohamed Ali, it became obvious that he has done the following:

1. Started a computer using a Windows installation media
2. Selected "Upgrade" upon being prompted with the following dialog box:

[image]

This is totally normal and by design: You cannot upgrade a version of Windows by booting into a Windows Setup. You must run Windows Setup from within the Windows you would like to upgrade.

[image]

Comment: How i must run Windows Setup from within the Windows i would like to upgrade? While my Windows is running.

Comment: If you want to upgrade, yes. Start Windows, go to Windows installation disk, run Setup.exe.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand you. Can you give me a video link which shows your mean ?

Comment: I added a photo. Video takes a longer to make.

Comment: Fine, but my data will be save?i mean other partitions.

Comment: Yes. They would be safe. But make a backup copy anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Fleet Command it upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 10 properly with keeping all my data and programs. I appreciate your effort a lot.

Comment: Sorry Fleet Command, But now partition C is full of unneeded programs such as Windows old. So, my question is (Is there is a way that i can get ride of these things?) If you said format C partition it's fine i don't care about C but i need a new and clean Windows 10 copy.

Comment: Of course it happens. Do know *anything* about Windows Setup at all?

Comment: I know but i am not professional i still studying.